Cómo hago para que el círculo creado en el mapa de leaflet conserve su tamaño sin importar el zoom
Estoy creando un círculo para agregarlo al mapa de leaflet pero este cuando en el mapa hace zoom al tamaño de la polilínea  usando "map_1.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds())" el círculo se vuelve diminuto y solo se puede volver a ver haciendo zoom al mapa. cómo lo soluciono?


L.circle([route.waypoints[1].location[1], route.waypoints[1].location[0]], {
                color: '#ff00ee',
                fillColor: '#ffffff',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                radius: 20,
                weight: 4,
            }).addTo(map_1);




No usas leaflet para general el circulo, sino que lo haces con HTML+CSS
